# Reflection on type aliases

Tags: scala, reflection, types, macros

How do you expand a `TypeRef` to a type alias to the original type (and type parameters) of the alias?

If I have a type referring to `Option[List[Double]]` and I do:

```
case myType @ TypeRef(_, sym, args) if myType <:< typeOf[Option[Any]] ⇒
```

I get:

- `sym` is `Option`
- `args.head` is `List[Double]`, and I can continue processing with the `Double` type.

*With Type Aliases*

If I have a type `Option[MyType]` and type alias `type Mytype = List[Double]` and I do:

```
case myType @ TypeRef(_, sym, args) if myType <:< typeOf[Option[Any]] ⇒
```

I get this:

- `sym` is `Option`
- `args.head` is `MyType`

How do you expand `MyType` to `List[Double]` with reflection? I have been able to determine that `MyType` is a `List`, but I can't get the nested type parameter `Double`.

---

***Scaladoc Refs***

[TypeRef extractor](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Types%24TypeRefExtractor):

```
TypeRef(
  pre: Universe.Type,
  sym: Universe.Symbol,
  args: List[Universe.Type])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `normalize` method on `Type` may help you:

> Expands type aliases and converts higher-kinded TypeRefs to PolyTypes.
>   Functions on types are also implemented as PolyTypes. Example: (in the
>   below,   is the type constructor of List) TypeRef(pre,  , List()) is
>   replaced by PolyType(X, TypeRef(pre,  , List(X)))

Having a type `t` you can also do something like `t.map(_.normalize)`. This will normalize `t` as well as all types that are part of definition of `t` (e.g. type arguments). So effectively this will get rid of any aliases that occur anywhere in `t`.